# How does CI determine it should run build?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

How does the TFS server (or other CI tools) determine it needs to run a build when the build trigger is set to CI? I've looked for documentation but all I could find was a vague "when a developer submits changes" or similar.

We have several solutions living in the same directory. These solutions are reusing some of the same projects:

Solution1

- projectA
- projectB

Solution2

- projectA
- projectC

If I set up builds pointing to Solution1 and Solution2 and then make changes in projectA, will TFS trigger builds for both solutions?

I know I can test this and see what happens. This is to illustrate the background of my question which actually is: how does TFS (or other CI tools) determine they need to run a build?

What if submitted changes are to files that are not in a solution? eg. build scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the Builds to run as CI Build, when TFS will trigger the build will be determined by the folders you add to your mappings on the trigger option.

Whichever source control folder you include in the Path filters under the Triggers Tab, any changes made on those folders will cause the build to run.

If you don't want the build to trigger when checkin is made in the build script file, it is better and recommended to place them in a different folder.

Thanks, let me know if it helped or not.